# Verificaton: use an appropriate substitution to solve this differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

It was trivial to show that the substitution $y=ux$ for $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$ gives

$\frac{udu}{\sqrt{1+u^2}(1-\sqrt{1+u^2})}$=$\frac{dx}{x}$. Now  I want to express this in terms of x and y.

Use subsitution $y=1-\sqrt{1+u^2}$
$\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{-u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$
$dy=\frac{-udu}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$

$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{-dy}{y}$
$ln(x)=-ln(y)+c$
 This does not seem correct though because taking the exponential of both sides gives $x=\frac{A}{y}$ which is obviously not the solution.

Am I meant to substitute $u=\frac{y}{x}$ in $y=1-\sqrt{1+u^2}$  ?

Comment: You should use a seperate variable for second substitution. It seems like you are confusing this $y$ for the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested, instead of using $y$ again, write $$p=1-\sqrt{1+u^2}$$

Following the same steps you took, you arrive at $$px=A$$

Whereupon, $$(1-\sqrt{1+u^2})x=A$$

Also, $u=\frac yx$, so substituting this in and rearranging gives $$\left(1-\frac Ax\right)^2=1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

setting $$y=xu$$ then we get $$y'=u+xu'$$ then we get $$u+xu'=-\frac{1}{u}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2}+1}$$